# flutter how to get call logs in Android and Ignore that specific code in IOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am working on a calling application project which requires to read call logs of Phone. but I need a simple and short code to do this, also I need to skip this in IOS(Because IOS does not supports reading Call Logs.) I need a simple and short code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a platform check to identify android and ios device.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid){
    //your android code
}

if (Platform.isIOS){
    //your iOS code
}
```

For reading call logs you can refer to call_log library
https://pub.dev/packages/call_log

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap everything about call logs into if block.

```
if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    //Do your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks but How can I read this call logs in flutter.